# How to move editText cursor?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm using an `EditText`. but the cursor starts off in the center of the screen. if I use `wrap_content` in the xml file, I can't see the `EditText` at all (it's hidden).

I'd like the cursor and the input text to start off at the top , under my toolbar. Any ideas?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_settings_contact_us"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="airjaw.butterflyandroid.SettingsContactUsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        />

    <Button
        android:text="Send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:onClick="submitButtonPressed"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How

[image]

Comment: add you full layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `android:gravity="top"` inside your `EditText` if you only need to move the cursor to top

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:gravity="top"
    />
```

**Edit** : use  `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` if there is any overlap or without that you can even use `android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar"`

**Edit 2**:  use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true` in your root layout where @id`activity_settings_contact_us` and use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` under your activity tag @ manifest! this is for you last question in the comment

Comment: Unfortunately that overlaps with my toolbar and I can't see the text.

Comment: @makthrow then add a margin with the height of tool bar to your edit text view using `?attr/actionBarSize`

Comment: @makthrow how is it now ^_^

Comment: Perfect! thank you. adding the gravity=top and the 
layout_below    worked.
is there a way to move my Send button up so that the keyboard doesn't hide the button when the keyboard appears?

Comment: @makthrow then you should mark my answer as the correct answer and key for your second question is `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`in your activity tag at manifest http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/ make sure you give the credit to the person who answers before if you want to ask another question off topic its a good practice at so.anyway answer is on my edited post

Answer (score 0):

Change the android:width to a dp value.
Ex.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText1" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Can't see the text I'm inputting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LinearLayout  instead of RelativeLayout.